# Open an accordion item from an external page

Tags: jquery, anchor, accordion, external-links

I want to open an accordion item from an external link.

Something like this:
A user clicks on a link on page-1 and page-2 loads and scrolls to the opened accordion item.

I used the word scroll as I will have several accordion items.

I tried to test some of the answers I found here but I wasn't able to customize them to work with my accordion.

Your help would be highly appropriated.

Thank you very much

My Accordion Structure:

```
 <div id="accordion" class="accordion">    

      <div class="accordion-item" id="item-1">
         <div class="accordion-header">
            Simple text 
            <span class="accordion-item-arrow"></span>
         </div>
          <div class="accordion-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Morbi quis egestas nulla. Vestibulum sit ame.t 
          </div>
     </div>

    <div class="accordion-item" id="item-2">
         <div class="accordion-header">
            Simple text 
            <span class="accordion-item-arrow"></span>
         </div>
          <div class="accordion-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Morbi quis egestas nulla. Vestibulum sit ame.t 
          </div>
     </div>

</div>
```

How the accordion works:
   "accordion-item" gets an active class when clicked and opens the "accordion- 
   content":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).bind("ready", function(){  
    accordion = jQuery("#accordion").accordion();
    });
</script>
```

Link structure on the external page (First page):

```
<button onclick="location.href='page-2.html#item-1';"> 
Open Accordion item one</button>

<button onclick="location.href='page-2.html#item-2';"> 
Open Accordion item Two</button>
```

Comment: On page holding the accordian, retrieve the query string (right now its wrong itself, no # to be used), then based on that, open the required tab from accordian.

Comment: Suppose you have url "page-2.html#item-1", just retrieve the text part after # character. Then after just do following: $('#<TEXT_AFTER_#_CHARACTER>').trigger("click");. It will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply NitinSingh, Can you write the code so I understand better?

Comment: Thanks for the reply  NeuralIT User , I think I need to see the codes, can you write them down please?

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code, so that will give you an update on it.

Comment: I don't know how to create a fiddle :(